# How to connect to standalone cassandra using pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, jupyter-notebook

Please forgive the naive questions but I am new to ML & distributed/no-sql databases. I have already installed stand-alone Cassandra and pyspark and verified that those installations (verified pyspark version from jupyter notebook, created key space/table etc.) . My goal is to be able to be able to connect to local/standalone cassandra keyspace/table using pyspark (jupyter).

I know there are some threads on similar topics, but most seem to be around datastax-cassandra not the standalone version, and don't seem to have a simple solution on how to install anguenot/pyspark-cassandra locally and make the connector work.

Here is what I have so far (windows 10 machine) :

1. Installed standalone pyspark in my local (C:\spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7)
2. Installed standalone Cassandra in my local (C:\cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.4)
3. Downloaded the zip file (https://github.com/anguenot/pyspark-cassandra/archive/v0.7.0.zip)
   (C:\Users\\Downloads\pyspark-cassandra-0.7.0.zip)
4. On my command prompt (spark bin directory), I am trying to run the following:

```sh
pyspark — py-files C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\\pyspark-cassandra-0.7.0.zip \
  --packages anguenot/pyspark-cassandra:0.7.0 \
  --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=172.0.0.1
```

5. I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Users\<path>\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-script.py”, line 9, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File “C:\Users\<path>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py”, line 230, in main
command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
File “C:\Users\<path>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py”, line 133, in _jupyter_abspath
‘Jupyter command `{}` not found.’.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.
```

6. Assuming this installation is completed, my next step would be to run the following in pyspark to connect to cassandra:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

load_options = { "table": "TABLE_NAME", "keyspace": "KEYSPACE_NAME"}
df=spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(**load_options).load()
df.show()
```

Thank you for all your inputs.

Comment: I had a similar problem when first installing some of these components, and the issue was that my path wasn't set up to find Jupyter commands. Can you check your system path?